# What is the definition of a read-only property in JavaScript? What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, readonly-attribute

I am a little confused on what a read-only property means? I know that `classList` is a read only property by MDN's definition but what does that exactly mean?

Comment: `something.classList = []` won't do anything. The value of the property cannot be changed.

Comment: You can only get (read) the property value, but you cannot set (write) a new value. So, this is ok: `myVariable = someObject.property`, but this is not: `someObject.property = someValue`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus. Is classList an object... ?

Comment: classList is a read-only property of the Element base class, though a number of API methods are provided to modify the returned read-only DOMTokenList. (add(), remove(), toggle(), contains() etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A read-only property means it cannot be overwritten or assigned to. Any such assignment will silently do nothing in non-strict mode. E.g.:

```js
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'property', {value: 123, writeable: false})


// Assign 456 to obj.property using the . syntax, but it's still 123
obj.property = 456;
console.log(obj.property);

// Assign 789 to obj.property using the [] syntax, but it's still 123
obj['property'] = 789;
console.log(obj['property']);
```

Or just error out with a `TypeError` in strict mide:

```js
'use strict';

var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'property', {value: 123, writeable: false})


// Assign 456 to obj.property in strict mode will result in a TypeError
obj.property = 456;
console.log(obj.property);
```

Answer (score 2):

When a property is read-only , the property is said to be “non-writable”. It cannot be reassigned.

for example you can not update or assign a value to the `classList` property of an element but you can read it.

For reference:

1. [Objects — Writable, Configurable & Enumerable](https://medium.com/@ayusharma.in/objects-writable-configurable-enumerable-365cdff6a408)
2. [JavaScript Object Accessors](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Beside what **@Mureinik** said there is another way to make an object in read-only mode
it called `freeze` you could use it like this example

```js
let myObj = {id: 45, title: 'title here'}

Object.freeze(myObj);

myObj.title = 'update title' // this wouldn't updates

console.log(myObj)

// incase if you want to rewrite this object after freezing it
// you need to re-assign all of its values like this 
myObj = {id: myObj.id, title: 'Another title here'}

console.log(myObj)
```

you could read about [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) and the right way to [update it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only#Valid_cases) in **mdn** docs

Comment: There's lot's of ways you can make a property read-only, they all boil down to setting the `writable` attribute to `false`.

Comment: @Bergi yah there is a lot i just mention what i know of them